# addCountry nullpointer error

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Can someone offer some insight on why the code doesnt work?

[edit: fixed code and new error]

I'm getting an error Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NullPointerException`
and an error at the `World.addCountry()` (at line 8) code and an error at the `addWorldplaces()` (at line 5) code according to my output.

I have a feeling it's something to do with not instantiating the `world` class? could it be possible?

```
public class World{

private Country[] countries;
private int numCountries=0;

public boolean addCountry(Country newCountry){
    if(!(newCountry==null)){
        countries[numCountries]=newCountry;

        numCountries++;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
       }
}

public static void addWorldplaces(World pWorld){
         Country usa=new Country("USA", 1);
        pWorld.addCountry(usa);
}
```

Comment: Dave has your answer in comment.

Comment: completely unrelated: instead of ```if(!(newCountry==null))``` you should write ```if(newCountry!=null)```. it does the exact same thing, but has the bonus of being quicker to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are actually objects in Java.  You need to allocate your `Countries` array before you can use it.  You'd typically do this in a constructor:

```
public class World
{
  private Country[] countries;
  private int numCountries;

  public World()
  {
    this.countries = new Country[16];       // allocate the array
    this.numCountries = 0;
  }

  ...
}
```

You need to size your array appropriately.  Alternatively, you could look at an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which will automatically grow in size if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly im still getting the same error, have no idea why..

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Didn't instantiate the `World` object (I didn't see where the `pWorld` first time instantiate)
2. Your array of `Country` didn't instantiate. You must do like this `private Country[] countries = new Country[10]`.

*Note:
Please post the stack trace of the Exception.*

Answer (score 1):

Greg Kopff is right, you have to initialize an Array before put something into it.

And in your case, the size of array is not determined, [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is better.
So you don't need to deal with extending array or country number yourself.

```
public class World {

  private ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

  public boolean addCountry(Country country) {
      if (country != null) {
          countries.add(country);
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  public int getCountryNumber() {
      return countries.size();
  }
  ...
}
```